# Issue with Java 1.8 and .pxf file exported from a keystore

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keytool

I have an issue when I try to install a .pfx file exported from java keystore, it's happen when I use Java 1.8 update 321.

Step by step:
C:\SSL> set path=%path%;"C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin"

C:\SSL> keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore reporting.jks -dname "CN=reportserver.itech.com, OU=Company, O=OCompany, L=BSAS, ST=BSAS, C=AR" -keypass Reporting1 -storepass Reporting1 -deststoretype PKCS12

C:\SSL> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore reporting.jks -destkeystore reportserver.itech.com.pfx -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12

C:\SSL> certutil –f –p Reporting1 –importpfx reportserver.itech.com.pfx

CertUtil: -importPFX command FAILED: 0x80090020 (-2146893792 NTE_FAIL)
CertUtil: An internal error occurred.

[graphic Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Ptl.png)

I tested it with java 1.7 and I don't have the same issue.

Any idea?

Comment: What Windows? Java [8u301 up](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u301-relnotes.html#JDK-8153005) (also 11.0.12 up and 16 up) switched to a newer better encryption for PKCS12 which my Win 8.1 rejects with the same error you got and my Win 10 accepts; I don't have 11 but expect it's the same. (So did OpenSSL 3.0.0, at roughly the same time.) There's a sysprop to switch back and/or you can configure it in detail in the applicable java.security file (see earlier in the same release notes).

Comment: I have Windows Server 2016 Standard.

Comment: That's odd; I'd expect S2016 to be the same as 10, at least assuming it's updated, but I can't test or investigate it myself. Anyway, try the compatibility setting; to pass a JVM option to `keytool` use `-J` here like `-J-Dkeystore.pkcs12.legacy`